# Uniqueness of non terminating binary decimals in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

How do we prove that non terminating binary decimals has a unique binary expansion? I notice that this question has been posted before but no answer has been given yet...Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you want to prove that every real number has a unique non-terminating expansion.

Suppose $a$ has two non-terminating binary expansions, since they are different they must be different in at least one of the digits, consider the leftmost digit that is different.

This exists since the numbers left of the decimal point are a finite amount, so we can label the leftmost digit 1, then 2, then 3 and so on, Therefore the digits in which they differ can be seen as a subset of the natural numbers, and every subset of the natural numbers has a minimum element

Let $b$ be the number which has the binary representation of the first digits up to the one that is different,if we consider the "big" representation of $a$ we have $a>b$ since it must have other non-zero digits after (otherwise it would terminate) on the other hand if we look at the "small" representation of $a$ we get $b\geq a$ since $a$ has the same representation as $b$ up to a point but then it has a smaller digit. therefore $a>b\geq a\implies a>a$, a contradiction.

Comment: I think it is very clear, thank you so much! Just one point , if I didn't misunderstand, the point b you choose is a terminating binary decimal, right? @Jorge

Comment: yeah $b$ is the number that is represented by the first digits of the two expansions that are the same,and the big one of the first digit that is different.

Comment: How do you define a real number (he casually asked)?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just using some of their basic properties that are given in most calculus texts