# Writing uniqueness binary expansions

Tags: proof-explanation, binary

I'm reading a solution to a problem that I don't fully understand. The statement writes out the binary expansion of a real number and requires that there is no natural number $N$ beyond which the binary expansion is $1$ forever.

I'm not able to understand (a) why such a binary expansion exists or (b) why this implies that the resulting binary expansion is unique. I'm not sure if there's an analogy with the ability to choose a decimal expansion for any real number that doesn't terminate in $9$'s.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me understand this.

Comment: It's exactly analogous to decimal expansions terminating in 9s.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Could you explain how?  For example, I know that $1.0 = .11\overline{1}$, but is this the only time binary expansions are non-unqiue (in which case if I require that the binary expansion not terminate in $1$'s, it's unique)?

Comment: Yes. It's like that for every base. If you write in base $a$, then the only source of non-uniqueness is that numbers can end with an infinity of $a-1$ (usually one encounters $a=10$ with decimal numbers, but here you have the case $a=2$).

Comment: Does this answer clarify it for you?

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/953430/412379

Comment: @MikeO'Connor It's helpful, but does "non-terminating" in this case mean "never $1$ forever"?

Comment: @JohnT non-terminating means it doesn't end in all 0s

Comment: @MikeO'Connor That seems to be a different notion then than binary expansions that are not $1$ beyond some point (or is it not?).

Comment: @JohnT - a terminating binary expansion has no 1s (i.e. only 0s) after some point. a non-terminating binary expansion always has some 1 after any point.

Comment: Ok, so that seems to be different than the binary expansions I described above then, but it seems that both requirements give uniqueness.